# Dynamics 365 Outlook App- Addon

Tags: dynamics-crm, outlook-addin, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics365-app-outlook

Simple question, is it possible to create an add on for the Outlook app for Dynamics 365. I want it to move an email to the archived folder as soon as we click track.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Dynamics 365 App for Outlook](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/dynamics-365-app-for-outlook-user-s-guide.aspx)?

While you can likely build an Addin that does what you need, it might already support this.